# How to get "Generated By" field in Webi?

Tags: business-objects, webi, business-objects-sdk

In my WebI Report I would like to print the Author or the Last modified User name.

How can I obtain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the manual *Using functions, formulas and calculations in Web Intelligence*, which contains a reference information regarding functions you'd need to retrieve this information. You can find the manuals for your specific version of BusinessObjects on [help.sap.com](http://help.sap.com).

The functions you're probably looking for are `DocumentOwner()` and `DocumentAuthor()`.

Update:

While you can't retrieve the user's full name in Web Intelligence, there is a workaround, provided that

1. You're using third-party authentication (e.g. Windows AD)
2. You're able to pull the full name from that source into the CMC

If so, you can use *User Attribute Management* to define a new user attribute in the CMC and then create a new dimension in your (UNX) universe which uses the `@Variable` to get in the new user attribute value.

From the IDT manual (paragraph 18.3.6 *About @Variable*, version BI 4.1 SP5):

> To reference a User Attribute, specify the internal name for the at­
>   tribute as it is defined in the CMC. `@Variable` returns the value of
>   the attribute for the current user. For example, the User Attribute
>   `MYCOUNTRY` contains the value of the country of each user in the CMC.
>   Specify the attribute's internal name surrounded by single quotes:
>
> `@Variable('SI_MYCOUNTRY')`
>
> The attribute’s internal name is defined when the attribute is cre­ ated in the CMC

User Attribute Management is described in the Administrator Guide, paragraph 6.2.17 *Managing attributes for system users* (version BI 4.1 SP5).

Comment: Hi Kristof, DocumentOwner() will give us the Login ID with what we login. Is there any way to get the First Name or LastName of the Owner, like say i login with s345243. But i want to display the name as Niki. Is this possible?

Comment: @Niki I updated the original answer as it was a little to elaborate to explain in a comment